# Partial Proof of Second Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture (modified)?

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs

I have obtained the following partial proof of the [Second Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSecond_Hardy%25E2%2580%2593Littlewood_conjecture&ei=Z3QxVO2ZDJSUuQT2i4K4AQ&usg=AFQjCNE4BKW0oh49I3KrsSRP7SHr_T4hKg&sig2=UAyWpEXPTlm2jwXk8KZ47A) of which I can't find out the logical flaw in the proof.

> ### Problem
>
> Prove that for all sufficiently large $x$ and $y$ such that $x\neq y$ and $x$, $y$ $\in \mathbb{R^+}$ we have,
>   $$\pi(x)+\pi(y)\geq\pi(x+y)$$
>
> **Proof**
>
> For a proof of this result we use the following inequality,
>   $$\dfrac{x}{\ln x-(1-\epsilon)}<\pi(x)<\dfrac{x}{\ln x-(1+\epsilon)}$$
>
> each of which hold for all sufficiently large $x$ and for any $\epsilon>0$.
>
> To prove,
>   $$\pi(x)+\pi(y)\geq\pi(x+y)$$
>
> Now note that, $$\pi(x)+\pi(y)>\dfrac{x}{\ln x-(1-\epsilon)}+\dfrac{y}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}$$ and for the same $\epsilon$ we may write, $$\pi(x+y)<\dfrac{x+y}{\ln (x+y)-(1+\epsilon)}$$
>
> Hence,
>
> $\pi(x)+\pi(y)\geq\pi(x+y) \\\impliedby \dfrac{x}{\ln x-(1-\epsilon)}+\dfrac{y}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}\geq\dfrac{x+y}{\ln (x+y)-(1+\epsilon)}\\\impliedby \left(\dfrac{x}{\ln x-(1-\epsilon)}\right)\left(\ln (x+y)-\ln x-2\epsilon\right)\geq \left(\dfrac{y}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}\right)\left(\ln y-\ln (x+y)+2\epsilon\right) \\\impliedby \left(\dfrac{x}{\ln x-(1-\epsilon)}\right)\geq\left(\dfrac{y}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}\right) \quad,\quad 2\ln \left(x+y\right)\geq\ln \left(xy\right)+4\epsilon$
>
> Both of which are true. The first one for sufficiently large $x$ and $y$ (because the function $f(t)=\left(\dfrac{t}{\ln t-(1-\epsilon)}\right)$ is ultimately increasing for all $1\geq\epsilon>0$) and the second one for all $\epsilon$ satisfying the bound $0<\epsilon\leq{\ln \sqrt[4]{2}}$. Thus, $$\pi(x)+\pi(y)>\pi(x+y)$$ holds for all $x,y$ satisfying the bound for the $\epsilon$ just deduced.

What is the flaw in the proof? Can anyone help me?

---

**Edit:-**

The deleted part of the question is now asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150516/partial-proof-verification-for-the-second-hardy-littlewood-conjecture).

Comment: The statement is existential, so no counterexamples could ever be found.

Comment: The theorem is of the form $\exists MP(M)$, it's an existential statement. Counterexample is a method of disproving universal statements alone.

Comment: It looks like you made major modifications to this post after receiving an answer; that is not good use of this site - it would be far better to post the new content as a separate question (and roll back this one). You'd be much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @Meelo: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to do that. As a matter of fact, if you go on seeing the edits, you will note that just one day after receiving the answer to my original question, I have edited the body of the text and immediately notified R. Israel. What surprises me most is that still the answer is being upvoted.

Comment: Here is a suggestion for a further modification: you can delete the first (in the logical sense, so last in the reading sense) implication because the inequality that follows from it (the only one that takes two lines) is obviously true due to the fact that left of the $\geq$ there is a positive number and right of the $\geq$ is a negative number.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the middle arrow? I cannot see how the interesting sounding inequality (the most upper one not involving $\pi$) follows from the trivial inequality below it. What do you do? Multiply enumerators and denominators with something?

Comment: @Vincent: For the elaboration of the middle arrow, I have taken the terms with numerator $x$ one one side and that having numerator $y$ on the other. Then observing that $\ln (x+y)-(1+\epsilon)>0$ for sufficiently large $x$ and $y$ such that $\ln \min(x,y)-(1-\epsilon)>0$ the middle $\impliedby$ follows.

Comment: Right, I see. It seems this implication actually works both ways.

Comment: Moving up, I don't see how you got the very first inequality, the one you introduce as 'we use the following inequality'. As far as I understand the Prime Number Theorem we have for every given $\epsilon$ that for all sufficiently large $x$ the following holds: $(1-\epsilon)\frac{x}{\ln x} < \pi(x) < (1 + \epsilon)\frac{x}{\ln x}$. This is not the same as what you write. How did you get your inequality?

Comment: @Vincent: See the section *Bounds on the prime counting function* of [this page](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPrime_number_theorem&ei=Jj82Vc-hEofm8AXcxIHoDQ&usg=AFQjCNERIpGZ7CXjPH9lzcGsonA45I5adA).

Comment: Very interesting! I'm still at a loss where, if at all, your proof is wrong. However here is something else I found. An (in my opinion) simpler way to obtain the first inequality not involving $\pi$'s is by deriving it from the two inequalities $\frac{x}{\ln x - (1-\epsilon)} \geq \frac{x}{\ln (x+y) - (1+\epsilon)}$ and the same thing with $y$ instead of $x$. Looking at the first of these we see that it is equivalent with $\exp(2\epsilon) \leq \frac{x + y}{x}$ which need not be the case when $y$ is relatively small compared to $x$.  This is interesting because ... (see next comment)

Comment: ...because all alledged counterexamples (assuming the first HL-conjecture) take precisely this form: x huge and y (relatively) small. Your derivation seems to make no assumptions on the *relative* size of x and y (only on the absolute size) but maybe such an assumption is still hidden in there somewhere?

Comment: @Vincent: The proof has a very curious history. One of my friend has given me the first proof. But it had a very serious flaw as has been noted by the given answer. Then I had tried to remove the mistakes but my attempt was also useless. My later attempts were largely influenced by [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://vixra.org/abs/1410.0066&sa=U&ei=fHQ4VZXSB5SdugSMvoCIBw&ved=0CAUQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFfSYwHxp-hoAjI6boMkEjjHMxspQ). I think that it will be better if you would directly send your comments to the author of the paper.

Comment: @Vincent: I don't understand why you remarked that for $\exp(2\epsilon)<\dfrac{x+y}{y}$ it need not be the case when $y$ is relatively small compared to $x$. Can you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: It is $x$ in the denominator, not $y$. $exp(2\epsilon)$ is roughly the same size as $1 + 2\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ you can even show (by drawing the graphs of $f(t) = 1 + t$ and $g(t) = \exp(t)$ that $\exp(2\epsilon) > 1+ 2\epsilon$. Now $\frac{x + y}{x} = 1 + \frac{y}{x}$ so if $y/x < 2\epsilon$ we have that the above inequality is false.

Comment: Aha, I see now that my earlier remark that the middle inequality is trivially true because the left hand side is positive and the right hand side negative was false. Ok, so I do need to seriously look at the first (downmost) implication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed above that the naive approach to proving the topmost inequality without $\pi$'s fails when $y/x$ is roughly the size of $\epsilon$ or even smaller. Now, it turns out that this inequality is indeed false when $y/x$ becomes small enough in terms of $\epsilon$. How small exactly is small enough however is considerably more subtle than I thought initially, see the end of this post. But first is a counterexample with actual numbers. Plugging the same numbers into the inequalities further down should tell us which of the implications is wrong.

$\epsilon = 1/6$ seems to be the nicest epsilon that is allowed. We do not know how large $x$ and $y$ must be to satisfy De la Vallée-Poussin's inequality but it is safe to assume that they are big enough to have positive denominators in the inequality we want to disprove. So, take $y$ big enough and take $x = 11y$. (So $y/x$ is quite a bit smaller than $\epsilon$ in this example.) We plug this into the inequality and simplify notation by setting $\ln y = z$ and hence $\ln(x) = z + \ln 11$ and $\ln(x+y) = z + \ln(12)$.

Divide both sides of the inequality by $y$ and multiply with the product of the three denominators: $(z - 5/6)(z + \ln 11 -  5/6)(z + \ln 12 - 7/6)$. What we end up with is an inequality between two quadratic expressions in $z$.

It is easy to see that both have quadratic term $12z^2$ so we can ignore that. We can also ignore the constant terms, since we are looking at 'sufficiently large $z$'.

So, just comparing the multiples of  $z$ on both sides we end up with an inequality that is equivalent to $12 \ln (12) - 11 \ln (11) \geq 24/6 = 4$ which is false.

The somewhat more general form of this equation (taking $x = ky$ instead of $x = 11y$) reads $(k+1)\ln(k+1) - k\ln(k) \geq 1/3(k + 1)$ or even more generally:

$(k + 1)\ln(k+1) - k\ln(k) \geq 2\epsilon (k + 1).$

Keeping $\epsilon$ fixed and viewing both sides as a function of $k$ we see on the left hand side a function that in the beginning increases quite fast, but as $k$ gets bigger increases more and more and more slowly, while at the right hand side we see a function that increases slowly, but keeps this steady pace of increasing and hence will eventually (for big enough $k$) become bigger. This is the reason we can construct counterexamples to the inequality as the one above. (Provided I got it finally right this time.)

On the other hand it seems that when we keep $k$ fixed we can choose $\epsilon$ so small that the inequality does hold. Hence the situation seems to be as follows: keeping $y$ fixed and increasing $x$ we might from time to time reach a  counterexample to the Hardy-Littlewood inequality. However keeping $k = x/y$ fixed and moving $y$ (and hence $x$) up it seems that we will eventually reach a point above which the weaker inequality $\pi((k+1)y) \leq \pi(ky) + \pi(y)$ does always hold. Though weaker than what the author of the article claims, this still sounds quite spectacular. I wonder if I'm not (still) overlooking something.

Comment: $7\ln 7-6 \ln 6>\frac{7}{3}$.

Comment: Also the function $f(x)=(x+1)\ln (x+1)-x\ln x$ is increasing and so since your claim is false for $k=6$, it must be false for all $k>6$.

Comment: Aargh, you are right. I delete my answer

Comment: O wait, I see that I forgot a bracket. A variant seems correct after all. I leave it up temporary and modify it later. Have to run now.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, hopefully everything is correct this time.

Comment: It is very much curious because, if I am not wrong then the inequality holds even if $\epsilon=\frac{1}{6}$ and $k=12$ by the argument given in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150516/partial-proof-verification-for-the-second-hardy-littlewood-conjecture).

Answer (score 7):

It's not true that $\pi(x) + \pi(y) > 2 \pi((x+y)/2)$ for large $x$ and $y$.

Consider $x = p-1$, $y= p+1$ where $p$ is a large prime.  Then $\pi((x+y)/2) = \pi(y) = 1 + \pi(x)$

---

**Edit:** The first mistake is
$$ 2\pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)<\dfrac{x+y}{\ln \left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)}$$
All you know is 
$$ \pi\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)<\dfrac{x+y}{\ln \left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: You missed my point. Find out the flaw in the method, don't give counterexamples.

Comment: Proof edited. Please check the edited proof.