# Partial proof verification for the Second Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Due to the comment of Meelo following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959502/partial-proof-of-second-hardy-littlewood-conjecture-modified) I think to post the currently-deleted part question as a separate question here.

---

The proof of the theorem as presented in [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://vixra.org/abs/1410.0066&sa=U&ei=fBF_VKLzJ5CD8gXkjoDIDg&ved=0CAoQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGmQKoJATP4jbUZR8Yf7EIkGM1dCA) is wrong (that's why I deleted one of post which asked to find the flaw in the proof in one of the theorems). However, after combining my argument with that of given in the paper, I think I have a correct proof of the first theorem of the paper. In the following I will be mostly copying from the paper but where my argument applies, I will express it in my own language.

> **Theorem 1 (modified)**
>
> For all $k>1$ and for all sufficiently large $y$ satisfying $\dfrac{y}{\ln y−(1−ϵ)}<π(y)<\dfrac{y}{\ln y−(1+ϵ)}$ for all $0<ϵ≤\ln \sqrt{2}$ we will have $π(ky)+π(y)>π((k+1)y)$.
>
> ***Proof (modified)***
>
> We start by noting that,
>   $$π(ky)+π(y)>\dfrac{ky}{\ln ky−(1−ϵ)}+\dfrac{y}{\ln y−(1−ϵ)}\tag{1}$$
>   and for the same $ϵ$,
>   $$\dfrac{(k+1)y}{\ln ((k+1)y)−(1+ϵ)}>π((k+1)y)\tag{2}$$
>   Hence proving,
>   $$\dfrac{ky}{\ln ky−(1−ϵ)}+\dfrac{y}{\ln y−(1−ϵ)}\ge \dfrac{(k+1)y}{\ln ((k+1)y)−(1+ϵ)}\tag{3}$$
>   Or equivalently,
>   $$\dfrac{k}{\ln ky−(1−ϵ)}+\dfrac{1}{\ln y−(1−ϵ)}\ge \dfrac{(k+1)}{\ln ((k+1)y)−(1+ϵ)}\tag{4}$$
>   will imply our inequality.
>
> Notice that the above inequality is satisfied if and only if, $$ k \left(\displaystyle \frac{1}{\ln ky-(1-\epsilon)}-\displaystyle \frac{1}{\ln (k+1)y-(1+\epsilon)} \right) \geq \left(\displaystyle \frac{1}{\ln (k+1)y-(1+\epsilon)}- \displaystyle\frac{1}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}\right)$$
>
> Now we take $\ln ((k+1)y)−(1+ϵ)>0$. Keeping in mind the bound on $ϵ$ as stated in theorem we note that for all $y≥\sqrt{2}e$ the inequality holds trivially for all $k>1$. Consequently, with this bound assumed on $y$ we conclude that the above inequality holds if and only if,\begin{equation}k \left(\displaystyle \frac{\ln \left(1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{k}\right)-2\epsilon}{\ln ky-(1-\epsilon)} \right) \geq \left(\displaystyle\frac{2\epsilon-\ln (k+1)}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}\right)\tag{5}\end{equation}
>
> Now, to prove $(5)$ we make use of the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\ln x−(1−ϵ)}$ for some fixed $ϵ$. We will be trying to prove that the function is increasing for all sufficiently large $x$.
>
> To prove this we note that $f′(x)=\dfrac{\ln x−(2−ϵ)}{(\ln x−(1−ϵ))2}$. Now if we assume that $f′(x)>0$ then this gives, $\ln x>(2−ϵ)$. Thus we get, \begin{equation}{x>e^{(2-\epsilon)}}\tag{6}\end{equation} Hence if we assume that $x>e^2$ then for all $ϵ<2$ we can say that the function $f(x)$ is increasing. Hence our claim is that for all $y>e^2$ and for all $k>1$ we get, \begin{equation}\displaystyle \frac{ky}{\ln ky-(1-\epsilon)}>\displaystyle \frac{y}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}\tag{7}\end{equation}
>
> Thus we are left with proving that
>   $$\ln \left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)−2ϵ≥2ϵ−\ln (k+1)$$
>   Or equivalently, \begin{equation}(k+1)^2 \geq ke^{4\epsilon}\tag{8}\end{equation} which holds for all $k>1$ and for all $0<ϵ≤\ln \sqrt{2}$.
>
> Hence the theorem is proved.

Can anyone suggest where the mistake is?

Comment: Ok, here I am confused about the statement of the theorem. (It is probably taken from the article) You say 'for all sufficient large y satisfying [inequality] for all $0 < \epsilon < \ln \sqrt{2}$...'. As stated it is not clear $y$ exists. For each fixed $\epsilon > 0$ there exist $M_\epsilon$ such that all $y > M_\epsilon$ satisfy the inequality. However, the smaller of these $y$ do not satisfy the inequality anymore when we replace $\epsilon$ by a smaller value of $\epsilon$. Let alone that there are $y$ satisfying the inequality for ALL $\epsilon$ arbitrarily close to 0.

Comment: However, in my answer to the other post I got somewhat convinced that a version of this can hold: for all k > 1 there is an $M_k$ such that $\pi(ky) + \pi(y) > \pi((k+1)y)$ for all $y > M_k$. (This still sounds a bit too good to be true, but at least I don't see the mistake, yet.) Now in this formulation $\epsilon$ only shows up in the proof: given $k$ you choose $\epsilon$ such that $k$ and $\epsilon$ satisfy some inequality that is derived from the inequality in your other post. Then, once you have $\epsilon$ you choose $M$ such that $y > M$ satisfy Poussin's inequality for that $\epsilon$.

Comment: What do you mean by $y$ exists?

Comment: As I note in the answer to the other question it is really important in which order you choose k and $\epsilon$. Given $k$ you can find $\epsilon$ so small that equation (3) holds an you can derive the modified modified theorem as in my previous comment in the way you describe, however if you choose $\epsilon$ first you can choose $k$ so big that equation (3) does NOT hold.

Comment: Maybe I am reading the statement of the theorem wrong but it seems like if you say for all $k$ and for all $y$ satisfying [condition] we have [result]. Now my claim is that it is not clear if there are ANY $y$ satisfying condition (of course if there aren't any the modified theorem is still true, but somewhat uninteresting.)

Comment: Here I read [condition] as 'for all $\epsilon$ in [range] the number y satisfies Poussin's inequality with that $\epsilon$'. This is a really strong demand on $y$ and I have no idea where to start looking for such $y$.

Comment: But maybe you intended the condition on $y$ to be read in a different way?

Comment: Actually it seems that you are right. The statement is phrased in a poor way. But I actually intended it to mean that "For all $k>1$ there is an $M_k$ such that for all $y>M_k$ the inequality holds and if that happens then $\epsilon$ must satisfy the bound." Do you think this version is all right?

Comment: Well yes I think so. Maybe even safer is to say 'For all $k > 1$ there is an $\epsilon > 0$ and an $M_k > 0$ such that for all $y > M_k$ Poussin's inequality holds. If that happens then $\epsilon$ must satisfy the bound, in addition to some other bound defined in terms of $k$. From Poussin's inequality it then follows that $y$ also satisfies $\pi(ky) + \pi(y) > \pi((k+1)y)$.'

Comment: The confusing part of the proof is that if you start with an arbitrary $\varepsilon$ in the bound and an arbitrarily large $k$ then also it seems that the proof works which by your argument given in the other post isn't. How are you going to explain this paradox from the argument of this proof?

Comment: Aaargh my reformulation of the theorem in the last comment is also false. In place of  Poussin's inequality I mean your equality (3). As for the paradox I will look into it later tonight

Comment: If in the argument we **first** chose $k$ and $\varepsilon\in(0,\ln\sqrt{2}]$ then can't we conclude that, "For all $k>1$ and $\varepsilon\in(0,\ln\sqrt{2}]$ there exists $y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ (depending on $\varepsilon$ only, and not on $k$) satisfying Poussin's inequality such that $$\pi(ky)+\pi(y)>\pi((k+1)y)$$for all $y\ge y_0$."?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is of no use to mathematics (unless we want to know how lousy cranks can be at mathematics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a long time, but now I got it...

We can rewrite $(5)$ in the form

$$A \cdot B \geq C \cdot D$$

and want to derive $(5)$ from the two inequalities 
$A \geq C$ (inequality $(7)$)
and
$B \geq D$ (inequality $(8)$).

Now both $(7)$ and $(8)$ are valid, but they do NOT automatically imply $(5)$. The reason is that $A$ and $C$ are positive and $B$ and $D$ are negative.

So $(5)$ reads 'a positive number far away from zero times a negative number close to zero is greater than or equal to a positive number close to zero times a negative number far away from zero'. This might be true or false, depending on more detailed information about the numbers.

In fact it is not hard to find values for which $(5)$ is true: $k = 6$, $\epsilon = 1/6$, $y = 1000$ AND values for which it is false: $k = 15, \epsilon = 1/6, y = 1000$.

Since the rest of your derivation is correct the same result (sometimes true, sometimes false) holds for the equivalent inequality $(3)$, as I noted already in answer to your other post.

Comment: Recently I was going through this post and reread your answer and was wondering if there is any way to resolve the problem that you mentioned in this answer. In this case, however, if we can find an upper bound of $\epsilon$ (independent of $k$) from the following inequality, $$\left(\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k}\right)+\ln(k+1)-4\epsilon\right)\left(\displaystyle \frac{y}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}\right)\ge\left(\displaystyle \frac{ky}{\ln ky-(1-\epsilon)}-\displaystyle \frac{y}{\ln y-(1-\epsilon)}\right)(\ln(k+1)-2\epsilon)$$then I think that the problem can be avoided.

Comment: In fact, it is interesting to note that a slightly general version of what you state [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150516/partial-proof-verification-for-the-second-hardy-littlewood-conjecture#comment2560391_1150516) can also be proved using almost a similar argument.

Comment: The theorem is: "For all $k>1$ there is an $\varepsilon>0$ and an $M_k$ such that for all $y>M_k$ and **for all $m\ge 1$**  Poussin's inequality holds. If that happens then $\varepsilon$ must satisfy the bound, in addition to some other bound defined **only** in terms of $k$. From Poussin's inequality it then follows that $y$ also satisfies $π(ky)+π(my)>π((k+m)y)$."